# HitTest Function with two parameters not initializing

Tags: actionscript-3, function, hittest

Hey guys so Basically what I'm trying to do is when my player collides with all 5 of the points MovieClips in an array and the Goal Movie Clip i want a text to appear saying "Perfect. But i cant quite accomplish this. I set up the function and it seems like it would but i think what might be wrong is the hitTest with all the Movie clips in the array.

Here is how i set it up:

This is in my loop Function:

```
private function gameLoop(e:Event):void 
    {

        perfectTextFunction();

            }
```

This is the function:

```
private function perfectTextFunction():void 
    {


        if (player.hitTestObject(mcGoal_1 && points))
        {
            trace("perfect Text");
                    mcPerfect = new perfectText();
                    mcPerfect.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
                    mcPerfect.y = (stage.stageHeight/ 2);
                    stage.addChild(mcPerfect);

        }
    }
```

The Trace doesn't pick anything up.

Here is how the points are added to the stage if needed:

```
public function addPointsToStage():void
    {            
         for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
         {
             trace(aPointsArray.length);
             points = new mcGainPoints();
             stage.addChild(points);
             points.x = startPoint.x + (xSpacing * i);
             points.y = startPoint.y - (ySpacing * i);
             aPointsArray.push(points);
         }

    }
```

Please any help would be appreciated! THank you!

VESPER here is how I made the NESTED LOOP:

```
//If all points are hit then Perfect Hit Text
                if (player.hitTestObject(mcGoal_1 || mcGoal_2)) 
                { 
                        var weHitAll:Boolean = true;

                    for (var s in aPointsArray)
                    {
                          weHitAll = weHitAll && player.hitTestObject(aPointsArray[s]);
                           if (!weHitAll) 
                           break;
                    } 
                    if (weHitAll)
                    {

                                trace("perfect Hit");
                                mcPerfect = new perfectText();
                                mcPerfect.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
                                mcPerfect.y = (stage.stageHeight/ 2) - 80;
                                stage.addChild(mcPerfect);

                                nScore += 25;
                                updateHighScore();


                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var weHitAll:Boolean=true;
for (var s in aPointsArray) {
    weHitAll = weHitAll&&player.hitTestObject(aPointsArray[s]);
    if (!weHitAll) break; // missed one, drop cycle
}
if (weHitAll) {
    trace('Perfect hit!');
    ... // etc
}
```

Function `hitTestObject` accepts only a single object as parameter, in order to check against an array you need to iterate through it, checking against one object at a time (here it's in `aPointsArray[s]`).

Comment: Wow would have never came up with that. Thanks so much Vesper ill check it out.

Comment: Okay so there was no error but there still seems to be a problem. Whenever i hit all the points or even 1 the trace is initialized and the text appears. Or if i hit the goal and only the goal the text appears. I added the information you provided inside my Function.

Comment: Oh okay i barely understood what you meant. So i cant make it test 2 Hittests

Comment: You can initiate this trace if goal is hit, so if you "perfectly" hit the goal thus hitting both the goal and all the points, then perfect hit message is displayed. You can use nested if blocks to perform this.

Comment: Oh okay i get you. Thanks so much. Ill test it out

Comment: Could i do somethinng like this:       if(weHitAll) {  if(player.hittesobject(mcGoal_1)){   trace(...)  }}        ???

Comment: You should do the reverse. `if (player.hitTestObject(mcGoal_1) { weHitAll=true; for(...) {...} if (weHitAll) { trace(...);...} }`

Comment: Hey Vesper do yu think you could help me out i did what you advised me to do but it doesnt work. I read the code thoroughly but still i cant find why. Their is no Errors it just doesnt do anything when ever it happens. I added the New code above with your name in the description

Comment: Alright so i made a function in my gameLoop called perfecttextFunction(); and added the code in their now it seems to work but the bugs i getting is if i just hit the goal then the trace is activated also my nscore counter goes up by a thousand so it added 25 for stages 25 frames/sec     how could i fix this? ill still try in the mean time thank you

Comment: You should clarify what conditions you want to be met before the goal is triggered. See, if you just barely need to connect, it's OK, but if you need say that your object that's colliding with the goal has to stop, you have to add velocity check.